# Bjarne Stroustrup explanation

Tags: c++

In the book "A Tour of C++" by Bjarne Stroustrup, in chapter 4.2 'Concrete Types', I found this paragraph:

> The representation can be private (as it is for Vector; §2.3) and accessible only through the member functions, but it is present. Therefore, if the representation changes in any significant way, a user must recompile. This is the price to pay for having concrete types behave exactly like built-in types. For types that don’t change often, and where local variables provide much-needed clarity and efficiency, this is acceptable and often ideal. **To increase flexibility, a concrete type can keep major parts of its representation on the free store (dynamic memory, heap) and access them through the part stored in the class object itself. That’s the way vector and string are implemented; they can be considered resource handles with carefully crafted interfaces.**

I thought vector does not store anything in the class object (i.e. static fields). It does store things on the heap but they are kept inside an object of the vector class. I looked at clang's impelementation of vector and saw only one internal field being static (static const unsigned __bits_per_word).

Maybe I misunderstood him? What does he mean by that?

Comment: Why do you think this has anything to do with static fields at all?

Comment: I'm not 100% sure of what Stroustrup is saying, but he seems to be saying that by keeping the necessary parts of the class within the class itself, but allowing allocation of storage outside the class the object can be consider "resource handles" (a/k/a a way to access the object) through the class interface). I don't see any deep Voodoo there, just an (in)artful explanation.

Comment: He's saying that if you modify the non-static fields, you have to recompile (obviously). You can stash much of the data in the heap, but it can never be everything. Then there's an example.

Comment: The term "class object" refers to an instance of a class.   Every instance of `std::string`  (and `std::vector`) needs to store some data related to the data it manages - for example, it needs to keep track of the beginning of the string (e.g. a pointer), the capacity (e.g. an allocated length, the value returned by the `capacity()` member), and the end of the string (e.g. the value returned by the `size()` member).    (There are other things managed by `std::string`, such as the allocator object used to allocate and deallocate memory).

Comment: Ok, maybe I misunderstood this paragraph. I recently was much into Python and there class is an object and that is why I probably started thinking that 'class object' is the class itself, and if something is stored in 'class object' then it is a static field. Where in fact he means 'class object' is just an instance of class, i.e. an object created from the class. Ok, now everything is clear. Thanks for your help guys.